# Google sheets Countif function with UTC timestamp

Tags: google-sheets-formula

I am trying to count number of IDs that exist as of a particular date (see Summary tab). However, since the dates (column A) in raw data tab are in UTC timestamp format, the formula returns 0.
My formula is `countif('raw data'!A:A,"<="&A2)`

1. How do I adjust the formula to convert UTC timestamps to datevalue within countif function.
2. I also would like to make this countif function work with arrayformula so that I don't have apply the formula on each row.
   Here is the sample sheet :
   https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1IFAAiguhKD0xK8SYsnzMBSar4IFAQPzZfIh0U44bZWI/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

Translate first your dates by

```
=arrayformula(if(A2:A="",,VALUE(left(A2:A,10))))
```

You can use

```
=sumproduct(('raw data'!D:D<=A2)*('raw data'!D:D<>""))
```

Now, if you want arrayformula to be applied, first make a query

```
=QUERY('raw data'!A:D,"select D,count(B) group by D")
```

then compute a total as following

```
={"Total ID";ArrayFormula(if(isblank(G2:G),,mmult(1*(transpose(row(G2:G))<=row(G2:G)),1*G2:G)))}
```

both formulas are on yellow cells

Comment: Thanks @Mike, how do I make it work with array formula?

Comment: In fact, you have a problem with your raw datas : sometimes dates are numbers (ok) and sometimes text (not ok). So, no method will give the right solution without translate data in true dates.

Comment: I have modified my answer to give a solution with arrayformula